# does "falling down stairs" mean something?

Tags: meaning

i'm watching british cop show about 80's cop. there's a scene where a lot of people are talking at the same time in police station. they are mostly immigrants or visitors from s.africa(i don't know it's relevant or not.). then one cop(A) got up and said and the other cop(B) added.

> A: a bit of hush, please. Nobody's falling down any stairs here!
> B: i don't know about that.

i don't know why A said "nobody's falling down any stairs" and does it have any idiomatic meaning? or does it mean 'nobody is hurting' or 'nobody is gonna hurt you' kind of way? so don't make a fuss and be quiet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a trope to say that "falling down the stairs" is a common coverup excuse for someone having been physically abused. The implication here is that, when police abuse a detainee, they would say that he "fell down the stairs" to explain away his multiple injuries and bruises.

In your example it seems that "nobody's falling down the stairs here" is a promise that there will be no police brutality.

Comment: Monty Python had a sketch where a policeman is trying to explain the accused person's bruises. Policeman: he tripped and hit his head. Judge: What on? Policeman: the big table down at the police station.